# C Programing : Parent & Child Process

Tags: c, process, parent, pid

I'm trying to figure this out, given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

char mynum='0';
int main(void)
{
   int i;
   pid_t fork_return;
   static char buffer[10];
   fork_return = fork();
   if (fork_return == 0)
   {
      strcpy(buffer, "CHILD"); /*in the child process*/
      for (i=0; i<5; ++i) /*both processes do this*/
      {
         mynum=i + '0';
         sleep(1); /*5 times each*/
         write(1, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
         write(1, &mynum, 1);
         write(1, "\n", 1);
      }
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {
      strcpy(buffer, "PARENT"); /*in the parent process*/
      for (i=0; i<5; ++i) /*both processes do this*/
      {
         sleep(1); /*5 times each*/
         write(1, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
         write(1, &mynum, 1);
         write(1, "\n", 1);
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Notice that `mynum` is a global variable.

- Child is incrementing the ASCII value of `mynum`
- Parent is not
- Child and Parent can take turns running

Why does child print `CHILD0`, `CHILD1`, `CHILD2`, etc whereas parent prints `PARENT0`, `PARENT0`, `PARENT0`, etc? Remember `mynum` is a global variable.

Also, if I fork a process, how come when I print their `pid`, their `ppid` are always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent and child processes have separate [virtual address spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Thus, an update to the global variable in the child process does not affect the global variable in the parent process. This is a feature known as [memory protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection), where memory allocated for one process is typically not accessible by a different process.

The `pid`, retrieved with `getpid()`, is the the process id of the process and each process has a unique one. The `ppid`, retrieved with `getppid()`, is the parent process id. So long as the parent is alive, the parent process id will be the `pid` of the parent process from which the child was `fork()`d. When a child process's parent dies, the child gets inherited by the `init` process, which has process id 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't matter if it's global variable, you use them in separate processes.